# Can't use React-Router in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a React app that's using Typescript.

React versions `"react": "^16.9.0"` and React-Router version `"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"`

My `App.tsx` file is set up like this:

```
const App: React.FC = observer(() => {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Route path="/1234">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
});

export default App;
```

But when I try go to `localhost:4000/1234`, I get the following error:

```
Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Where I should see the `<Home />` component instead.

Your help with be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the problem of React-Router. It's because of Content-Security-Policy.

For more information, please check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy.

And you can try adding the following meta tag to your public/index.html file.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: *">
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using Express as well, so using Ton Carrier's answer, as well as the below in my `index.ts` file:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {                       
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'the path to your react project', 'index.html'));                               
});
```

The key here is that `'*'`, otherwise it breaks.